# выборка данных из файла python

Tags: python

Есть `txt` файл и один `input`. Нужно реализовать выборку из него. Если введенный в `input` текст совпадает с тем, что есть в файле то показывать все что есть как список. Например как в `вконтакте` когда поиск ведется.
Может есть какие-то готовые решения на `python`?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А поточнее сформулировать можно?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin обновил вопрос.

Comment: Что такое "все что есть"? Как выглядит "показывать как список" и что именно там должно быть? Как именно должно совпадать "совпадает". Если я ввел "лес", а в файле есть "колесо" - это совпадает?

Comment: @Эникейщик `все что есть` это первые совпадения, то есть `лес` не совпадает с `колесо`.

Comment: Вам что в итоге то нужно? Строку, где есть вхождение, само вхождение, его позиция или еще что-то? Можете привести пример исходных данных и требуемого вывода?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно найти все вхождения подтекста в текст. Для этого есть множество быстрых алгоритмов, например с помощью Z-функции, как [здесь](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/z_function) (Там снизу написано применение для вашей задачи). Асимптотика будет O(len(txt) + len(input)) времени и памяти.